# Templated HTML in forEach

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script where I get the multiple rows from a spreadsheet and I want to send an email per each row.

The problem is that I have an HTML template where I have some data dynamically, and when I run the `data.forEach()` function, it won't recognize the values I have.

My data looks like

| Student | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Robert | 8 |
| David | 6 |
| Frank | 9 |

My script

```
    function sendMultipleEmails() {
    const rawData = ss.getRange("A1:B3").getValues();
    let data = [];
// I prefer working with Object Literals rather than Spreadsheets array of arrays way
    rawData.forEach(value => {
        data.push({
            name: value[0],
            score: value[1],
        })
    })
    data.forEach(value => {
        let emailTo = "example@gmail.com";
// In subject, value.name works, because it's set in the code
        let subject = `Scores for ${value.name}`;
        let body = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("scores");
        et message = body.evaluate().getContent();
        let options = {
            htmlBody: message,
        }
        GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, body, options)
    })
}
```

My template, where value.name and value.score don't work, because the parameter value in forEach is not recognized by HTML

```
<h2> Hey <?= value.name ?> </h2>
<p>This is your score <?= value.score?></p>
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let body = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("scores");
et message = body.evaluate().getContent();
```

#### To:

```
let body = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("scores");
body.value = value; // Added
et message = body.evaluate().getContent();
```

Comment: Fast, simple and working, thank you so much @Tanaike